# C++, why are errors ignored by my windows terminal?

Tags: c++, windows, terminal

I start learning C++ and I try to create an error to learn how to handle it.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int main(){
        int res{ 120 }, div{1};

    std::cin >> div;

    try {
        std::cout << res / div << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception& err) {
        std::cout << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Ended" << std::endl;
        
        return 0;
}
```

The program compiles but at the execution, when I enter "0", the code stop and the error isn't shown.

I use the command "g++ -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Werror  main.cpp -o result" to compile.
I use the Windows terminal or the same terminal in VSCode and I installed g++ with mingw64.
I use the version of g++ 12.2.0

Comment: Integer division by zero leads to *undefined behavior*, not a C++ exception. You need to add explicit code to protect yourself from it (e.g. `if (div == 0) { ... }`)

Comment: The program crashes. `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` to see it.

Comment: Change `std::cout << res / div << std::endl;` to `if (div == 0.0) throw std::runtime_error("divide by zero"); std::cout << res / div << std::endl;`

Comment: Did the operating system tell you there was a divide by zero exception? That's not a C++ exception, even though it's called the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no exceptions for division by zero in C++. (There may be something with a similar name on the OS or architectural level though.)

If you do integer division by zero in C++, then your program has undefined behavior and you don't have any guarantees on how it will behave. For floating-point division by zero, the ISO C++ standard also gives the program undefined behavior, but commonly it will produce `INF`/`-INF`/`NaN` (e.g. if the compiler implements IEEE 754).